# Where can we check how long until Monero is in private beta?

Tags: support

I checked on Area 51, and it doesn't seem to list it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monero SE is in public beta now.

Answer (score 16):

Currently private betas run about three weeks. Barring any unforseen technical difficulties, this site is slated to open to the public on **Tuesday afternoon, 8/9!**

In the next iteration of the private beta workflow, these milestones will be listed more explicitly and be easier to discover.

Answer (score 4):

Private beta lasts at least 21 days.

So far Monero has been in private beta for 20 days as can be seen [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)

Public beta could start anytime as soon as tomorrow. My answer is somewhat vague because the decision is made on a case by case basis.

All we can do is remain active and make sure our private beta content is of high quality. To that end I recommend reading [this](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39/lets-not-vote-up-everything-also-do-not-reopen-everything).