# Is this type question too broad?

Tags: discussion

[This quantum computing plan question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/484/is-there-a-formal-plan-in-place-for-the-transition-to-quantum-computing-if-so) may lead to some important answers but seems impossible to answer in its entirety today.

Is this a good example of a question that should be closed as "too broad"?

Can those with experience in other stacks estimate the frequency that otherwise good questions, closed for being too broad result in the person asking the question to produce a revised question? What can we do to avoid discouraging newcomers to the stack by closing questions that could become valuable if revised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a good example of a question that should be closed as "too broad"?

Yes. It's asking eight questions in a single post. I usually answer with a [default reply](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/a/215/87):

> It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Also, this question has 10 upvotes and is totally within the scope of my recent post on these concerns as explained here:

- [Let's not vote up everything, also do not reopen everything](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/39/100)

Comment: Thanks! I just voted to close and borrowed you language

Comment: It's not _my_ language, check [this app](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

Comment: @5chdn when questions with lots of votes are edited after closure (like this one) is it better to leave it close and require a new question be asked instead of reopening an edited version (with its existing count of upvotes)?

Comment: Number of votes does not matter. But that's the whole idea. If a question gets maintained and improved regarding the raised concerns, you can always cast reopen votes.